# Flastlist issue showing posts one by one

Tags: react-native, scroll, infinite-scroll, flatlist

I'm using flatlist to show a feed of posts (like tiktok), the issue is that sometimes is showing up a part of the second post instead of scroll down to it. See the picture below:

[image]

That issue happens when I'm scrolling down faster.
Flatlist code:

```
          <FlatList
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={videos}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            onEndReachedThreshold={3}
            onEndReached={() => {
              if (!isFetching) {
                debouncedFetchMore();
              }
            }}
            snapToInterval={PICTURE_HEIGHT}
            disableIntervalMomentum
            viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
            onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
            onRefresh={() => getPosts('video', FetchMode.REFRESH)}
            refreshing={false}
            //Optimization
            renderItem={renderItem}
            removeClippedSubviews
            initialNumToRender={1}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
            windowSize={2}
            // Scrolling fixes
            decelerationRate="fast"
            snapToAlignment="start"
            overScrollMode="never"
            bounces
            scrollEventThrottle={8}
            getItemLayout={(_, index) => ({
              length: PICTURE_HEIGHT,
              offset: PICTURE_HEIGHT * index,
              index,
            })}
            pagingEnabled
            ref={refFlatList}
          />
```

Comment: Try with [react-native-pager-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view)

Comment: How can I do "onEndReached" using that library?

Comment: `onPageSelected={e => e.nativeEvent.position}` you will get current active page after that you will compare with your array length and do fetch more thing.
Also you can use in your flatList renderItem as view.